# Stack Overflow and Server Fault accounts do not share info

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, users, serverfault

Shouldn't my Stack Overflow and Server Fault users be the same? I logged into SF using the same OpenID as I do on SO, and I'm a total new user. Shouldn't my profile at least transfer over?

Comment: If you use the same OpenID, you can copy your profile from one site to the next.  Each site has *separate* points, though.  FYI, questions like this belong on Meta (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to [associate your accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites) and then you can just copy your profile over in the Accounts tab of your target sites profile.

Answer (score 4):

Just a note that Google is a bit of an exception here.  They generate a unique openID for you for every site where you use it, and so if you use Google's openID there is no way to have the *same* openID at StackOverflow that you do at ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: associate tab advice still applies, though